# Valgrind memory leak with dynamic arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've tried several ways to fix this, but cant seem to figure it out. Valgrind is pointing to a memory leak with my resize method and I feel like I might be missing something simple.

.h file

```
private:
  int* pArray;     // stores math expression
  int currentSize; // size of array
```

.cpp

```
void Prog::resize(int newSize)
{
  cout << "Address of polynomial:\t\t\t" << &pArray << endl;
  int* temp = new int[newSize] {0};
  cout << "Address of temp:\t\t\t" << &temp << endl;
  copy(temp, pArray);
  delete[] pArray;
  pArray = temp;
  cout << "Address of pArray after swap:\t" << &pArray << endl;

  temp = nullptr;

  currentSize = newSize;
}

void Prog::copy(int* to, int* from)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
      to[i] = from[i];
  }
```

I added the cout's to see what is happening with the address because I thought after swapping the pArray to temp that it would print out the address of what temp's location, but it seems to keep its original location. Is that what is supposed to happen?

I've tried creating a swap method and the issue is still the same when I use it.

```
void Prog::swap(int*& to, int*& from) 
{
  int* temp = to;
  to = from;
  from = temp;
}
```

This is the output when I run my program and from Valgrind.

Program snip

```
Address of pArray:                  0000006741EFF218
Address of temp:                    0000006741EFEEE8
Address of pArray after swap:       0000006741EFF218
D = +50x^20000 +15x^11 +5x^10 -12x^7 -4x^6 +30x^5 +4x^4 -2x^3 +50
```

Valgrind

```
==22696== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 12
==22696==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22696==    by 0x40230A: Prog::resize(int) (Prog.cpp:332)
==22696==    by 0x401DD7: Prog::operator=(Prog const&) (Prog.cpp:171)
==22696==    by 0x400DEE: main (lab1.cpp:36)
==22696==
==22696== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 12
==22696==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22696==    by 0x40230A: Prog::resize(int) (Prog.cpp:332)
==22696==    by 0x401DD7: Prog::operator=(Prog const&) (Prog.cpp:171)
==22696==    by 0x400DD5: main (lab1.cpp:35)
==22696==
==22696== 52 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 12
==22696==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22696==    by 0x40230A: Prog::resize(int) (Prog.cpp:332)
==22696==    by 0x401DD7: Prog::operator=(Prog const&) (Prog.cpp:171)
==22696==    by 0x40201D: Prog::operator*=(Prog const&) (Prog.cpp:214)
==22696==    by 0x40116D: main (lab1.cpp:55)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit - The assignment operator shows a memory leak as well but it uses the resize method which is why I left it out, but here rest of the code requested:

```
Prog::Prog() : currentSize(1)
{
    pArray = new int[currentSize] {0};
}

Prog::~Prog()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
      this->pArray[i] = 0;

    currentSize = 0;

    delete[] pArray;
    pArray = nullptr;
}


Prog& Prog::operator=(const Prog& rhs)
{
  if (this == &rhs)
    return *this;

  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    pArray[i] = 0;

  if (this->currentSize < rhs.currentSize)
  {
    resize(rhs.currentSize + 1);
    currentSize = rhs.currentSize;
    pArray = new int[currentSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
      pArray[i] = rhs.pArray[i];
  }
  else
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < rhs.currentSize; j++)
      pArray[j] = rhs.pArray[j];
  }

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Please post your constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, as the problem is perhaps in how `operator=` treats the returned data. (Oh, and investigate `std::shared_ptr` and friends as they will simplify things)

Comment: Leak is in Prog::operator=(Prog const&)  (Prog.cpp:171) that you avoid posting.

Comment: @KenY-N I added the rest. I am not allowed to use smart pointers at this time (although I haven't seen shared_pointer mentioned). I cannot use anything from the STL library (vectors or arrays that carry its size etc)

Comment: @endanegered -- You really should code a copy constructor `Prog::Prog(const Prog&)`.  Then your assignment operator would become a 3-line function using `swap`.

Comment: Apart from other concerns, if `newSize < currentSize` then the call of `copy()` in `Prog::Resize()` has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `operator=`, you call `resize`, then essentially do the same thing again in the next two statements.  Since `resize` allocates memory (and stores that pointer into `pArray`, then you overwrite that value in `operator=` with a new one without freeing the previous value, you get the leak.

Comment: Wow... I was just looking at the wrong place and assuming it was resize since it was in every block lost. Thank you! I was losing my mind and it was staring at me in the face.